# Подсчитать пустые чекбоксы и передать id

Tags: javascript

есть такая функция, Отписаться. Т.е. есть форма где несколько чекбоксов, выбрал чекбоксы и нажал отписаться вышло сообщение. Функцию указал, она работает как нужно.
Задача в том, что я добавил еще кнопку Подтверждение, на нее вешаю похожую функцию, например, Subscribe. 
Вот только по вызову должно передаваться сразу 2 списка - чекнутые чекбоксы (cheked) и пустые чекбоксы (unchecked).

```js
function Unsubscribe() {
 
      const inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

      console.log(inputs);
      
      var ids = "";

      for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        console.log(inputs[i]);
        if (inputs[i].checked) {
          ids += inputs[i].id + ',';
        }
      }

      if (ids.length > 0) {
        const Email = document.location.href.split('?')[1];
        const url='https:/www.site.com/unsubscribe?' + Email + '&id=' + ids.substring(0, ids.length - 1);
        document.location.href=url;
      }

    };
```

Comment: Есть какая-то проблема в этой функции?

Comment: в указанной нет, проблема как я указал выше, делаю вторую на основе данной, но не пойму пока как передать и отмеченные и не отмеченные чекбоксы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const bt = document.getElementById( 'unsubscribe' );
const ch = document.querySelectorAll( 'input[type="checkbox"]' );

bt.addEventListener( 'click', click );

function click () {
    let href = 'https:/www.site.com/unsubscribe?';
    let checked = [ ], unchecked = [ ];
    ch.forEach( i => i.checked ? checked.push( i.id ) : unchecked.push( i.id ) );
    if ( checked.length ) {
        href += 'checked=' + checked.join( ',' );
    }
    if ( unchecked.length ) {
        href += '&unchecked=' + unchecked.join( ',' );
    }
    // ...
    console.log( href );
}
```

```html
<button id='unsubscribe'>Unsubscribe</button>

<input type="checkbox" id='1'>
<input type="checkbox" id='2'>
<input type="checkbox" id='3'>
```

Comment: функция на onclick разве не должна вызываться? поправил путь в subscribe, к сожалению никакой реакции, и на страницу https:/www.site.com/subscribe?' не переходит.

Comment: поправил, проверяю

Comment: @Joseff ...ааа... я просто не понял что у вас вторая функция ведет на другой адрес `https:/www.site.com/subscribe` - это только понятно из вашего коммента выше, но не из вопроса. Но в примере же все понятно как собрать чекбоксы(и в консоли видно), а как вы ими управлять будете, это уже ваше дело. И в вашем примере нет необходимости указывать переменную как `id=1,2,3`, вы же и так знаете что это `id`, лучше реализовать сбор идентификаторов в одной общей функции(для всех действий), а переменные использовать как я и указал, чтоб было понятно какие `id` `checked`, а какие `unchecked`.

Comment: Все отлично, Вы все мне указали, заодно и направление, что нужно почитать про события.

Comment: )) Хорошо, принял с сведению.